# How to test Passport Local Session Authentication with Postman?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman, passport.js

I'm using Passport Local Strategy using session authentication, not JWT tokens.
I'm also using connect-mongo as my session store. The project uses Typescript targeting ES6.

I'm having trouble persisting authentication across two Postman requests.

Relevant code:

```js
// index.ts

import express, { Request, Response, Application } from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';
import passport from './passport/setup';

const app: Application = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGOURI;

mongoose
    .connect(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(db => {
        console.log(`Mongo DB connected at ${MONGO_URI}`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(session({
    secret: "mysecret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: MONGO_URI
    })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// register routes
// app.listen
```

```js
// passport/setup.ts

import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import User from '../models/users';
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';
import { NativeError } from 'mongoose';
import { IUserDoc } from '../models/users';

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err: NativeError, user: IUserDoc) => {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

const localStrategy = new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, (email, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() }, (err: NativeError, user: IUserDoc) => {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: `User with email ${email} not found.`});
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch: boolean) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            }

            return done(null, false, { message: `Invalid email or password.` });
        });
    }); 
});

passport.use(localStrategy);

export default passport;
```

First Postman request I try to login. A Cookie is returned with name `connect.sid` with value such as `s%3AzHKxYJlyXIod_n32GbnXs9G4GFh7-0Cl.MwgW%2Bm7IlGMTapAg%2B9OCJt6tjiGXphJMcFj7LuYJ8J8`.

In the MongoDB instance `sessions` collection, I do see a session with `_id` as `zHKxYJlyXIod_n32GbnXs9G4GFh7-0Cl`, which corresponds to the first part of the `connect.sid`.

Second Postman request I try to access a route that returns true or false depending on if I'm logged in. The request has a cookie in its request headers with value `connect.sid=s%3AzHKxYJlyXIod_n32GbnXs9G4GFh7-0Cl.MwgW%2Bm7IlGMTapAg%2B9OCJt6tjiGXphJMcFj7LuYJ8J8`.

However, the route returns false.

In Postman, if I disable cookie jar in the settings for the second request, which means "Prevent cookies used in this request from being stored in the cookie jar. Existing cookies in the cookie jar will not be added as headers for this request," I get the desired result.

However, if I do this, repeatedly executing the second request will create a new session for each and new entry in the DB.

What I'm suspecting is that the second request spawns a new session and so that's why it is not authenticated. When I disabled cookie jar, I'm forcing the second request to keep using the session created by the first request, as it should. However, this explanation fails to explain why executing the second request right after the first request fails.

Comment: try with resave=true

Comment: @JRichardsz those options don't seem to change the outcome. However, I did notice simply deleting the saved cookie in postman works.

Comment: #1 I will try on my local. I implemented a kind of server for spas and I did not have your problems.  #2 Also, if you are developing the classic : web (mongo session + passport) + api (jwt), I advice you to test the web with a browser. Postman is to emulate programmatic invocations to APIs.